# Transactions and Batch Size

Tags: data-loader

If I set a batch size of 1 in dataloader and update around a million records, is there a guarantee that in a single transaction, only 1 record will be updated  - that is every record will be updated in its own transaction?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you will get each record it its own transaction, but you'll also use 1,000,000 API calls against your [daily limit](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.salesforce_app_limits_cheatsheet.meta/salesforce_app_limits_cheatsheet/salesforce_app_limits_platform_api.htm). In other words, if you have less than 1,000 Salesforce licenses, you're likely to exceed your daily limit, so you might need to run your update in smaller sets to stagger the API calls so you don't block other API requests. From a practical standpoint, even if you can't update in batches of 200, you should select the largest possible batch that doesn't cause errors for performance reasons.